# PHP7 and mongodb old querynot work

Tags: php-7.1

I have update my php 5.6 to php 7 and update mongodb driver also. but now my old code is not working on new environment.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes i have install in php7 mongodb using pecl.

then use https://github.com/alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter.

then use composer and change the code according to mongo-php-adapter library.
then its work.

enjoy :)